# Php upload blob picture without the use of submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I would like to upload a blob picture using a link tag like this example:

[Code sample](http://jsfiddle.net/7aGEv/3/)

And by this sample code to make the link tag to act as input file type picture:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#upload_link").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#upload:hidden").trigger('click');
    });
});
</script>
```

What is the best way to insert picture without the use of submit button? Should I insert some php code into the jquery function? How would I get the value of the selected file by the user?

Comment: why u need addslashes and file_get_contents to upload image? paste your full code to debug.

Comment: File uploading is different from normal form posting with ajax. You will need to imitate the browser form post with file data. Many examples and libraries are there. http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax, https://github.com/LPology/Simple-Ajax-Uploader

Comment: Hello thanks for answering and helping me! I would just like to change my question. What would you suggest me the best way to upload picture after the user clicked the link and browsing for the file?